# Should I not be using the mysql gem now for rails 3.0 applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm starting a new rails 3.0 application that uses geometry data types in the database to store polygons. I have installed the spatial adapter gem but it requires the mysql gem and is incompatible with the mysql2 gem.

Is it ok to use the mysql gem instead of the mysql2 gem? Am I going to have problems down the road?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't have any troubles. The main push for using the mysql2 gem over the previous mysql gem is that the mysql gem currently blocks I/O while waiting for a response from the db server, while the mysql2 gem doesn't. Unless you're focusing on optimizing your app for asynchronous components and concurrency, you probably won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're perfectly safe using the mysql gem with Rails 3. I've used it without any difficulties.